# How fast can you win against a passive opponent in the Innistrad block format?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, puzzles

There have been legacy decks in the past that were able to win a game in the first round, without even giving your opponent a chance to act. I wonder how many rounds minimum it would take to win a game in the Innistrad block format. In this format there are only cards allowed from Innistrad, Dark Ascension and Avacyn Restored.

The assumptions are:

- Your opponent is totally passive and does not play more than a single land each turn until he loses.
- You start with the perfect hand and each card you draw is the perfect card.
- The deck must be legal.

Please show the winning sequence with your answer.

Comment: I like this question. It's open-ended, but you can still compare different answers to see which ones are better. It will be interesting to see how things change when Avacyn Restored is released.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution for turn 2 on the draw. I can't seem to hit turn 2 on the play, but I -think- it's possible.

Edit: This looks kinda ugly, so here's a link to a picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw30D.png

```
                                                                           Mana Pool           Cards in Hand
Turn one                                                                    0                   8
Plains                                                                      W                   7
Doomed Traveler                                                             0                   6

Turn two                                                                    W                   7
Mountain                                                                    WR                  6
Infernal Plunge, sacrificing Doomed Traveler                                WRRR                5
Infernal Plunge, sacrificing Spirit, hold priority                          WRR                 4
Increasing Vengeance, targeting Infernal Plunge                             WRRR                3
Increasing Vengeance, targeting Infernal Plunge                             WRRRR               2
Increasing Vengeance, targeting Infernal Plunge                             WRRRRR              1
Resolve Infernal Plunge                                                     WRRRRRRRR           1
Desperate Ravings, discarding Past in Flames                                WRRRRRR             1
Doomed Traveler                                                             RRRRRR              0
Flashback Past in Flames                                                    R                   0
Flashback Infernal Plunge, sacrificing Doomed Traveler                      RRR                 0
Flashback Infernal Plunge, sacrificing Spirit, hold priority                RR                  0
Flashback Increasing Vengeance, targeting Infernal Plunge                   RRRRRR              0
Flashback Increasing Vengeance, targeting Infernal Plunge                   RRRRRRRRRR          0
Resolve Infernal Plunge                                                     RRRRRRRRRRRRR       0
Flashback Desperate Ravings, discarding any card                            RRRRRRRRRRR         1
Devil's Play for X=8, hold priority                                         RR                  0
Flashback Increasing Vengeance, targeting Devil's Play, dealing 16 damage   0                   0
Resolve Devil's Play, dealing 8 damage                                      0                   0
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to do it with Mindshrieker:

1. Forest, [Avacyn's Pilgrim](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=243212).
2. Island, [Mindshrieker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=229960).
3. Mountain, [Infernal Plunge](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=235603). Activate Mindshrieker three times on yourself, milling three [Blasphemous Act](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=222206)s for +27/+27. Attack with Mindshrieker for 28 (-8).

This uses only six cards, and even wastes a mana on turn 2.

Here's a variant that doesn't use any red cards:

1. Forest, Avacyn's Pilgrim.
2. Island, Mindshrieker, Avacyn's Pilgrim.
3. Activate Mindshrieker twice, milling two [Ghoultree](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=262662)s for +16/+16. Attack with Mindshrieker for 17 (3). Swamp, [Bump in the Night](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=222203) for 3 (0).

This uses seven cards.

Answer (score 3):

How about an alternate win condition?

1. Forest, [Avacyn's Pilgrim](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=243212).
2. Island, Avacyn's Pilgrim.
3. Island, [Mirror-Mad Phantasm](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=227297).
4. Activate Mirror-Mad Phantasm, conveniently milling your entire library. Island, [Laboratory Maniac](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=230788), [Thought Scour](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=262838). You try to draw from your empty library, and win.

You can use [Cackling Counterpart](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=245195) to copy the Phantasm, which guarantees that it will always empty your library, but doing so requires an extra turn.

Comment: From the OP's assumtions, "each card you draw is the perfect card" so I don't think the Cackling Counterpart is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Let's get the ball rolling:

1. Forest, [Young Wolf](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=262872). ([Reckless Waif](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=222111) would also work here.)
2. Attack with Wolf for 1 (19). Mountain, [Infernal Plunge](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=235603), [Markov Blademaster](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=249419). [Hunger of the Howlpack](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=243257) on the Blademaster.
3. [Furor of the Bitten](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=234431) on the Blademaster. Attack with Blademaster for 6 (13) and 7 (6) and Wolf for 2 (4). Mountain, [Fling](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=262871) the Blademaster for 8 (-4).

This wins on turn 3 on the play, leaving you with no cards in hand.

Answer (score 2):

Turn 1) Island, [Delver of Secrets](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=226749).

Turn 2) Reveal [Dream Twist](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=243213) (Transform **Delver of Secrets** into **Insectile Aberration**), Forest, [Wreath of Geists](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=237017) enchanting **Insectile Aberration**, Dream Twist (targeting self, milling 3 creatures). Attack with enchanted Insectile Aberration for 3+3=6 (13).

Turn 3) Forest, Wreath of Geists, Wreath of Geists, Dream Twist (targeting self, milling 3 more creatures), Attack for 6+6+6+3=21 (-8).

No cards in hand (total cards used 9) or remove **Wreath of Geists, Dream Twist** flashback the Dream Twist** instead of using a second copy in Turn 3) for 2 cards in hand, 6+6+3=15 (-2) life for opponent, and a more efficient less overkilly win.

Comment: Stacking Wreaths and Dream Twists is good value. I like it!

Answer (score 2):

1. Forest, Avacyn's Pilgrim.
2. Forest, Strangleroot Geist, swing for 3.
3. Mountain, Infernal Plunge the Pilgrim, then using the mana generated cast a 2nd Infernal Plunge on the Geist, Now with 5 Mana, cast Trepanation Blade and equip to the returned undying Geist, Swing with Geist. Enemy player reveals 14 non land cards, so you deal 17 damage.

Answer (score -1):

1 Mountain

2 Mountain, [Immolating Souleater](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=233058)

3 Pay 18 life to pump up Souleater to a 10/1. Attack for 10. [Fling](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=262871) Souleater for another 10.

This uses 4 cards

Comment: He limited this to cards in Innistrad, Dark Ascension and Avacyn Restored.

Answer (score -1):

1. Mountain, Memnite, Infernal plunge, Immolating Souleater.
2. Mountain, Pay 18 life to pump Souleater to a 10/1, Swing for 10, Fling Souleater for 10 damage.

Comment: Immolating Souleater is from the wrong edition.